# How to get the current viewName(not action name) in ASP .NET MVC3(beta)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization

I want to use Internationalization for that i need current viewname(not actionname) so that i can accordingly display specific view for that selected culture.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
          string cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        //String ViewNameOnly= do something to get viewName 
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewNameOnly))
            ViewNameOnly= filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] + "." + cultureName;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    ViewResultBase view = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
    if (view != null) {
        string viewName = view.ViewName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to say that if you don't return any ViewName in the ActionResult, it will give you empty and therefore in this cases you need to set `viewName` as `/Controller/View`

Answer (score 1):

`filterContext.Result` will contain the result returned from the controller action. This is an  `ActionResult` which is a base class for the various results. If it is a `ViewResultBase` (or one of its derived types), then the `ViewName` property will give you what you need.