# ASP.NET MVC: How to access View Name in a Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have written below Action Filter for model validation-

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
        var viewNme = filterContext.Controller;
        if (!viewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewData = viewData,
                ViewName = "Test"

            };
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

if I do not pass   `ViewName = "WhitePaper"`  It fails with below message - 
Server Error in '/Travelers.eBusiness.Travelers.Web' Application.

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

My question is - 
How do I pass view info ?

Comment: You want to get the view name for the current action method?

Comment: Yes I would like to have the viewname

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to get the current viewName(not action name) in ASP .NET MVC3(beta)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8910219/181087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result's view name on the `OnActionExecuted` event.

This should give you the view name.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{       
    var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
    var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
    if (view != null)
    {
        string viewName = view.ViewName;
        // If we did not explicitly specify the view name in View() method,
        // it will be same as the action name. So let's get that.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        }
        // Do something with the viewName now

    }
}
```

`filterContext.Controller.ViewData` will be available (not null) after the action method got executed. But if you want this in the `OnActionExecuting` event, you might consider reading the action name and use that ( Assuming your action method is returning a view without explcitly specifying a view name.)

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   var actionMethodName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
   // This will be same as your view name if you are not explicitly
   // specifying a different view name in the `return View()` call

}
```

Comment: this does not solve the purpose .This filter is for model validation . The view name returned here is of the redirected Page.

Comment: We are specifying a different view name in the `return View()` call

Comment: Then you cannot get the view name until the method is executed because your action method can return any views based on some condition.